# Tiled Map Editor and draw order in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, draw, tiled

I have a similar problem to:
[stackoverflow](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103442/how-do-i-determine-the-draw-order-of-isometric-2d-objects-occupying-multiple-til)

**But in my case I'm using Unity3D + TiledMapEditor + Tiled2Unity.**

I'm loading my map to Unity3D by Tiled2Unity program and as a player parameter Order in Layer I can change easily by:

```
Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
renderer.sortingOrder = -(int)(transform.position.y * 100);
```

Object "map" can only change the parameter Order In Layer for the individual layers.

For example: floor = 0, wall = 1, collision = 2. **I have no idea how to get to a single "tile" the map and change its Order In Layer** because of where it is located. To map was drawn from top to bottom (The lower the Order in Layer increased).

The script hooked the object "map":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using UnityEngine;

namespace Tiled2Unity
{
    public class TiledMap : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int NumTilesWide = 0;
        public int NumTilesHigh = 0;
        public int TileWidth = 0;
        public int TileHeight = 0;
        public float ExportScale = 1.0f;

        // Note: Because maps can be isometric and staggered we simply can't multply tile width (or height) by number of tiles wide (or high) to get width (or height)
        // We rely on the exporter to calculate the width and height of the map
        public int MapWidthInPixels = 0;
        public int MapHeightInPixels = 0;

        public float GetMapWidthInPixelsScaled()
        {
            return this.MapWidthInPixels * this.transform.lossyScale.x * this.ExportScale;
        }

        public float GetMapHeightInPixelsScaled()
        {
            return this.MapHeightInPixels * this.transform.lossyScale.y * this.ExportScale;
        }


        private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
        {
            Vector2 pos_w = this.gameObject.transform.position;
            Vector2 topLeft = Vector2.zero + pos_w;
            Vector2 topRight = new Vector2(GetMapWidthInPixelsScaled(), 0) + pos_w;
            Vector2 bottomRight = new Vector2(GetMapWidthInPixelsScaled(), -GetMapHeightInPixelsScaled()) + pos_w;
            Vector2 bottomLeft = new Vector2(0, -GetMapHeightInPixelsScaled()) + pos_w;

            Gizmos.color = Color.red;
            Gizmos.DrawLine(topLeft, topRight);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(topRight, bottomRight);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(bottomRight, bottomLeft);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(bottomLeft, topLeft);
        }
    }
}
```

to better understand (because my level of English is poor):

[mesh.png](https://s21.postimg.org/bjsxabw8n/image.png)

[map.png](https://s21.postimg.org/6z6qvecjb/image.png)